# how to store multiple values for one key in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I searched a lot to find a way to store multiple values into one key, but I can't anything

I need to set 3 value for one key in the PHP array

Is that possible to do this?

Comment: Make it an array:  `array('key' => array(1,2,3))`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski in this case how can i get value of key ? 
for example second array of key value :-/

Comment: Review [PHP arrays](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) For example `$array['key'][1]` has the value `2`.  And `$array['key']` has the array value `array(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 5):

To directly answer your question, no. PHP arrays can only contain one set of data for the key.

You need to use a multidimensional array, where the value of a key is an array with keys and values, e.g.:

```
$array = array
  (
    "bob" => array
                    (
                      "height" => "6.0",
                      "age" => "21",
                    ),
    "joe" => array
                    (
                      "height" => "5.9",
                      "age" => "35",
                    )
  );
```

[Here's a starting point for the basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

After that, there's a mountain of info already on Stack Overflow and the rest of the internet. Search for "php multidimensional array"

[Search here on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20multidimensional%20array)

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```
arr1 = array(
    'key1' => array(
                 'hello','im','a','array'
             ),
);
```

It would be better to learn the php basic's

Answer (score 1):

if you want to store multiple values in a single key. use array inside an array

example

```
$temp['value']=array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2');
```

is the possible solution