# How to push duplicate entry in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Following is an object:

```
$obj = (object) [];
$obj->{'key1'} = 'val1';
```

Now, how do I push a key with same name but different value?

```
$obj = (object) [];
$obj->{'key1'} = 'val1';
$obj->{'key1'} = 'val2';
```

It just edits the `key1`. I know this is an expected behavior but do we have other workarounds?

I want the schema to be like:

```
"collection": {
    "obj1": "val1",
    "obj1": "val2"
}
```

Comment: Instead of you should add array object inside the same key

Comment: I inserted the schema I want. Please look at the edited schema!

Comment: it will be better to use array and then typecast it to object, rather then creating array and typecasting it to object.

Comment: But it will be something like this: `[{}, {}]`

Comment: well keys can not be same! i suggest that you can use objects/array in collection to do this. 
"collection": [
    {"obj1": "val1"},
    {"obj1": "val1"},
]

Comment: so you trying to use MongoDB in PHP? please provide details what lib you using.
Also, as I understand your problem is that you need to store in collection Array of some custom-type objects in certain let's say "column" ?

Comment: right ! i think this will better solution because there us no concept allowing us to use same keys.

Comment: @2oppin I am using Swagger API.

Comment: But yeah I guess I will go with editing the keys to other names! Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can map the values in an array with "key1" as key:

```
$obj = (object) [];
$obj->key1 = ['val1', 'val2'];
```

**Output:**

```
{#183 ▼
  +"key1": array:2 [▼
    0 => "val1"
    1 => "val2"
  ]
}
```

Now, you can easily traverse for "key1" and get all the values.

Thanks!

Comment: I inserted the schema I want. Please look at the edited schema!

Comment: Hi Sanjay, You can't have more than one values for a single key.

Comment: Even if you have a way, think about how you will be accessing the values for "key1"

Comment: For further clarification, you can checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786351/how-to-store-multiple-values-for-one-key-in-php-array

Answer (score 0):

The default PHP object behavior, like many other languages, is that key must be unique. If it exists it will be updated.

There is not other workaround, unless you want to just make that value of the key an array and add to it if you set the value for an existing key.

E.g.

```
$obj = (object) [];
$obj->{'key1'} = 'val1';
```

Object is:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["key1"]=> string(4) "val2" }


$obj = (object) [];
$obj->{'key1'} = array();
$obj->{'key1'}[] = 'val1';
$obj->{'key1'}[] = 'val2';
```

And now object is:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["key1"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "val1" [1]=> string(4) "val2" } }
```

Based on that you could create a custom object that does that when you assign a value to an existing key:

```
class MyObj {
  private $data = array();
  public function __set($key, $val) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->data)) {
      if (!is_array($this->data[$key])) {
        $this->data[$key] = array($this->data[$key], $val);
      } else {
        $this->data[$key][] = $val;
      }
    } else {
      $this->data[$key] = $val;
    }
  }
  public function __get($key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->data)) {
      return $this->data[$key];
    }
  }
}
```

So now you set them like this:

```
$obj = new MyObj();
$obj->key1 = 'val1';
$obj->key2 = 'val2';
$obj->key1 = 'val3';
```

And the result is:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($obj->key1);
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => val1
    [1] => val3
)
```